# JIRA REST API -- Create Project HTTP 400 error

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I have downloaded latest version of Jira (https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/download) and have set it up on my laptop. I am trying to use the REST api for creating a project and running into issues , I am using java for making the call.

the JSON I am sending is -- `{\"key\":\"VSPRJ\",\"name\":\"FROMVSPROJ\",\"projectTypeKey\":\"software\",\"description\":\"VSPROJDESC\",\"lead\":\"ADMIN\",\"assigneeType\":\"PROJECT_LEAD\"}`

Java code snippet I am using is below

```
private static ResponseEntity WriteProjectIssueInformation2Jira()
{
    httpHeaders = createHeadersWithAuthentication();

    String createProjJSON = createCreateProjectJSON("INEMP2", "EMPMGMT", "com.atlassian.jira-core-project-templates:jira-core-project-management","business","ADMIN","PROJECT_LEAD","10000","0","http://atlassian.com","10324","0","0","projfromcode");

    String url = JIRA_URL + "/rest/api/2/project";

    System.out.println(url);
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(createProjJSON, httpHeaders);

    return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
}
```

I am getting 400 not matter what I change w.r.t to the JSON I am sending , I have tried the project GET api's and it returns back data. Both the sample java program and JIRA is running in my local laptop.

Not sure if there is any permissions required , please help

Comment: It should be problem with request only. Refer https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/about-the-jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue#JIRARESTAPIExample-CreateIssue-Data this may help.

Comment: Thanks. I have checked the link earlier and it doesn't have a sample for Creating Project. The reason I am saying it could be permission issue is after seeing this thread -- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/atlassian-connect-dev/s9uyP3tmxu4

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the lead attribute in the json, i created a user gave necessary permission and gave this userid as value for lead attribute and it started working